# Why does JavaScript use `variable_name: variable_value` in an object when only the variable itself is specified?

Tags: javascript, object

```
const partId = 10;

const newTask = {
  partId,
  'text': 'baz',
  'date': '2022-03-01'
}

console.log(newTask);
```

`partId` literally has the value of `10`, so I would expect this value to be substituted into newTask, i.e.

```
{
  10,
  'text': 'baz',
  'date': '2022-03-01'
}
```

(which would be an invalid object).

Instead my output is:

```
{
partId: 10
text: "baz"
date: "2022-03-01"
}
```

So it seems JavaScript will set the 'key' to the variable name when no 'key' is supplied.

**Question: Why would this be desired behaviour? Or have I completely misunderstood how this works?**

- My understanding of coding is it is a discipline where being explicit/avoiding ambiguity is best
- In this example it seems JavaScript is purposefully not interpreting code exactly as I have written it
- My gut feeling is I would rather get an error, than for JavaScript to "fix" my code for me

**NB:** I am coming to Javascript from Python - am I holding on to "Explicit is better than implicit." too dearly?

Comment: That’s a newer feature. It keeps the code more terse

Comment: *avoiding ambiguity is best* - what is ambiguous about this syntax? What is the other way that this syntax could be interpreted?

Comment: @justjoelaw, before the 2015 version of javascript, the code you show was a syntax error. Then they decided to support it as a shorthand for what you see now: set the key to the variable name, set the value to the variable value. If you prefer to be explicit, you still can, as in `partId: partId`.

Comment: `{
10,
text: "baz",
date: "2022-03-01"
}` isn't valid JavaScript. An object contains key/value pairs. It doesn't contain values without keys.

Comment: @jabaa they know that "`(which would be an invalid object)`"

Comment: @Konrad the other way this could be interpreted is as the literal value of `partId` (i.e. `10`, rather than `partId: 10`.

The equivalent python code throws a syntax error

Comment: @NicholasTower In that case, we're discussing why the designers of the language made the decision to add syntactic sugar for object literals?

Comment: @jabaa yep! That's what the conversation looks like to me.

Comment: Does this answer the question: Someone made a proposal and the board accepted it.

Comment: In mathematics, we can drop multiplication signs between variables e.g. `kl + 4 = 6`, but it's ambiguous, it can be interpreted as a variable called `kl` instead of `k times l`. Should we remove all shorthands like this then?

Comment: Okay, it seems to boil down to a trade-off between always being explicit and being terse. @Konrad that is a good point regarding  mathematics - I had not thought of it in that context.

Comment: I don't see how `{
  partId,
  'text': 'baz',
  'date': '2022-03-01'
}` could be called ambigous. It's a shorthand for `{
  partId: partId,
  'text': 'baz',
  'date': '2022-03-01'
}`. There is no way it could mean `{
  10,
  'text': 'baz',
  'date': '2022-03-01'
}`. Is `const a = 2, b = 3;` ambigous because you only have one `const` for two variables?

Comment: @jabaa the issue is rather that the beginners could expect this to throw an error. Similar to `if (x == 3)` vs `if (x = 3)` which doesn't throw an error

Comment: @Konrad Python and JavaScript are two different languages with many large differences. You shouldn't expect anything from Python in JavaScript. Every good introduction book explains shorthands for literals in the first chapters. Learning Python to code JavaScript will result in many bugs and unexpected results.